# how can I customize a searched result in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

someone help me am stucked.

I have a react native app and I managed to use search to match contents in an array, if searched word is contained in that array, the object it contains will be shown no matter how many objects it is. But my problem is how can I be able to highlight the specific word in that object that is shown...eg

word searched = "hello"

array = [
{

"this text contains hello"

}, {

"hello dear"

},

{ "hello, are you there? }

]

Basically, all objects in the array contains hello, and which means all three objects will be displayed to me ..but how can I make the particular text stand out (highlighted) ?

Tried something like this

```
  import {
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  SafeAreaView,
  BackHandler,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { hymnsCollection } from "./data";
import styles from "../../styles/App";
import listStyles from "./Styles";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

const List = ({ searchFilter }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const data = hymnsCollection;
  let keyWord;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container2}>
          <View style={styles.container3}>
            {data
              .filter((val) => {
                let search;

                val.stanzas.map((e, i) => {
                  if (
                    e.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter.toLowerCase()) != -1
                  ) {
                    search = e;
                  } else if (val.id.indexOf(searchFilter) != -1) {
                    search = val;
                  }
                });

                return search;
              })
              .map((datas, id) => {
                return searchFilter === "" ? (
                  <View key={id}>
                    <Text
                      style={styles.hymnTitle}
                      onPress={() => {
                        navigation.navigate("content", {
                          info: data,
                          id: id + 1,
                        });
                      }}
                      selectable={true}
                    >
                      <Text style={styles.hymnNumber}>{`${datas.id} - `}</Text>

                      <Text style={styles.hymnTitle} selectable={true}>
                        {datas.title}
                      </Text>
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                ) : (
                  <View key={id} style={listStyles.container}>
                    <Text
                      onPress={() => {
                        navigation.navigate("content", {
                          info: data,
                          id: datas.id,
                        });
                      }}
                    >
                      <Text
                        style={listStyles.hymnNumber}
                      >{`${datas.id} - `}</Text>

                      <Text style={listStyles.hymnTitle} selectable={true}>
                        {datas.title} {"\n"}
                      </Text>

                      {datas.stanzas.map((e, i) => {
                        if (
                          e.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter.toLowerCase()) !=
                          -1
                        ) {
                          keyWord = e;
                        }
                      })}
                      <Text style={listStyles.hymncontents}>
                        {keyWord.replace(searchFilter, searchFilter)}
                      </Text>
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                );
              })}
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply split the array text based on `searched` input. And then wrap the matched text in a `b` tag (boldening is just and example, you can style it however you want) and rest of the text in a span.

here is an example (not perfect)

```
import React from 'react';

const HighlightWord = ({ text, word }) => {
  const textParts = text.split(word);
  const result = [];

  textParts.forEach((p, i) => {
    result.push(<span>{p}</span>);
    if (i < textParts.length - 1) {
      result.push(<b>{word}</b>);
    }
  });
  return result;
};

export default function App() {
  const [term, setTerm] = React.useState('hello');
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { text: 'this text contains hello' },
    { text: 'hello dear' },
    { text: 'hello, are you there?' },
  ]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input value={term} onChange={(e) => setTerm(e.target.value)} />
      <ul>
        {items
          .filter((i) => i.text.includes(term))
          .map((i) => (
            <li key={i.text}>
              <HighlightWord text={i.text} word={term} />
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dv4hg7?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: hi thanks a lot but can you relate it to native? I tried but seems am having a difficulty ...

Comment: I just updated with my full code...